# Laravel returns empty string after ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to post a input value live to Laravel on input change and return an array with all matching data to the query. However I receive an empty array all the time. I have tried alot of things to get it working but without succes.

console says:

Object 
levels: "[]" 
status: Object
**proto**: Object

matchvalue has a value in console, the query does work when I change $this->type to a string that is in the database. So the root of the problem is the $request and $request->type, but I cant find a solution.

I would appreciate all the help, because I have really reached the end of the line on this problem. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#question_type input").on('change', function postinput() {
        var matchvalue = $(this).val(); // this.value
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "{{route('get-levels')}}",
          dataType: "json",
          data: matchvalue
        }).done(function(response) {
          console.log(matchvalue);
          console.log(response);
          $('#question_type').append(response.levels);
          console.log(response.levels);
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset class="form-group form_section" id="question_type">
  <h5>Selecteer in type vraag</h5>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
       <input class="form-check-input input" type="radio" name="type" id="exam" value="exam">
        Examenvraag
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="form-check-input input" type="radio" name="type" id="practice" value="practice">
        Oefenvraag
    </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>


ROUTE

Route::post('/selectQuestion/selection/levels', 'SelectionController@getLevels')->name('get-levels')->middleware('auth');



CONTROLLER

public function getLevels(Request $request){
        
  $this->_type = $request->type;
        
  $levels =
   Question::
      distinct()
             ->where('type', $this->_type)
             ->orderBy('level')
             ->get(['level']);

  return response()->json(['levels' => strip_tags($levels), 'status' => $request]);
 }
```

Comment: try echo json_encode(['levels' => strip_tags($levels), 'status' => $request]);

Comment: @omi same result unfortunaly :(

Comment: In your jQuery ajax call `data` needs to be in a key/value pair string (query string). Or passed as an Object/array which will then get turned into a query string by jQuery. Meaning it should be something like `type=yourvalue`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I tried {matchvalue: matchvalue} but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` attribute in your JavaScript code should be:

```
data: { 'type': matchvalue }
```

Change the line:

```
$this->_type = $request->type;
```

to:

```
$this->_type = $request->input('type');
```

Verify that `$this->_type` has the input captured from your form.

You can also try changing your query to:

```
$levels = Question::distinct()->where('type', $this->_type)->orderBy('level')->get()->lists('level');
```